# How to assign an object of a class to a value

Tags: java, object

here is what I am trying to do; User is going to input integer 1 or 2. Depending on the number, it will call the assigned object from a class. An example as follows;

```
Hero spiderman = new Hero();

Villain venom = new Villain();

int chosen;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Pick one character by number either 1 or 2");

int input = sc.nextInt();

    switch (input) {

    case 1:
        chosen = spiderman;
        System.out.println("You picked Spiderman");
    case 2:
        chosen = venom;
        System.out.println("You picked Venom");
    }

    chosen.fight();
    chosen.block();
```

I know 'chosen' is not the right type for objects, but how could I do that?
I don't necessarily do this way, but I need to be able to call objects depending on the input User putin.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hero` and `Villain` are `Objects` so you can't assign it to `int`.
I would make a class (maybe abstract) `Character` which would be extended by your two classes mentioned above. As I see both your classes has method `fight()` and `block()` so by polymorphism you could make `Character character = new Spiderman();` or `Character character = new Villain();` and then call `character.fight();` and `character.block();`

```
Character character;
int chosen;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Pick one character by number either 1 or 2");
int input = sc.nextInt();

switch (input) {

    case 1:
        character = new Spiderman();
        System.out.println("You picked Spiderman");
    case 2:
        character = new Venom();
        System.out.println("You picked Venom");
    }

character.fight();
character.block();
```

and don't forget about

```
public class Hero extends Character
public class Villain extends Character
```

Comment: Note: you could also use an `interface`. By the way, `Character` is not the greatest name due to possible confusion with `java.lang.Character`, and if it is not intended to be instantiated, should be `abstract`.